# R: pass a vector of symbols into a function instead of a long argument list

Tags: r, arguments, symbols

I'm writing an R package that calls C code with the .C() function. I need to pass over 50 arguments into .C(), which seriously bloats my code and is prone to error. Rather than type

```
output <- .C("my_dynlib", arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, ..., arg53)
```

I would rather have a character vector `myNames` of additional arguments to send to .C() and do something like

```
f <- Vectorize(as.symbol, "x")
mySymbols <- f(myNames)
output <- .C("my_dynlib", mySymbols)
```

But this isn't quite what I want because mySymbols is a list. Is there a way to compactly pass a collection of arguments to a function that I don't want to rewrite?

Footnote: I'm guessing that some of you will suggest passing more complicated arguments with .Call, .External, or Rcpp, but that's more overhaul than I want to deal with right now.

---

**Edit: what if I want `myNames` to point to slots in an s3 or s4 object?**

Suppose I want to use symbols that refer to class slots in a data frame.

```
> y = data.frame(a = 1:4, b = 5:8)
> myNames = paste("y@", slotNames(y), sep = "")
> mySymbols = lapply(myNames, as.symbol)
> str(mySymbols)
List of 4
 $ : symbol y@.Data
 $ : symbol y@names
 $ : symbol y@row.names
 $ : symbol y@.S3Class
```

I use do.call like @josilber said, but do.call doesn't recognize the symbols

```
> do.call(print, mySymbols)
Error in (function (x, ...)  : object 'y@.Data' not found
```

even though I can use those symbols manually.

```
> y@.Data
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3 4

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a list of objects that you want to pass to a function, you can do so with the `do.call` function. In your case, it sounds like the following should work:

```
do.call(".C", c("my_dynlib", mySymbols))
```

Comment: @ssdecontrol yeah -- the OP said in the question that `mySymbols` is a list.

Comment: Wow, that's really cool! I can even shorten the full thing to `output = do.call(".C", c("my_dynlib", lapply(myNames, as.symbol)))`. I have to do some more rewriting and debugging before I actually test it out, but thanks!